# Como hacer URLs Amigables?

Tags: php

Esto lo tome de inernet pero  no se que orden tendra en las carpetas asi que busco la manera de probar este codigo empleando formas de practca para probar este codigo para verificar si esta bien y continuar  mi estudio de mvc.

**index.php**

```
<?php

$router = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($router,'?') ) {
  $router = strstr($router,'?',true);
}
function router($url, $closure) {
    $route = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strpos($route, '?')) {
        $route = strstr($route, '?', true);
    }

    $urlRule = preg_replace('/:([^\/]+)/', '(?<\1>[^/]+)', $url);
    $urlRule = str_replace('/', '\/', $urlRule);

    preg_match_all('/:([^\/]+)/', $url, $parameterNames);


    if (preg_match('/^' . $urlRule . '\/*$/s', $route, $matches)) {

        $parameters = array_intersect_key($matches, array_flip($parameterNames[1]));
        call_user_func_array($closure, $parameters);
    }
}
```

**.htaccess: esta se encuentra en la misma ruta  principal que index**

Options -MultiViews
    
    RewriteEngine On

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Que error te sale? te agradecemos ser lo mas especifico en tu problema para poderte ayudar, al igual que las cosas que ya haz hecho.

Comment: ese codigo lo tome de internet pero no se como probarlo; es decir quiero comprobar si en realida me limpia las URL.

Comment: Aqui el link por si no me entiendes amigo, este link tiene los pasos pero no se como probarlos ya que el partio de este ejemplo http://dominio.tld/tienda/productos?search=libro , este es el link https://abalozz.es/rutas-amigables-con-php/

Comment: Para crear variables amigables puedes usar la [Notación Húngara](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_h%C3%BAngara)

Comment: Visto lo visto, creo que lo que quiere el OP es construir URLs amigables, no _variables_ amigables. Creo que deberías cambiar el título de la pregunta, porque se presta a confusión.

Comment: Variables "amigables"?  ಠ_ಠ, puedes invitarles un a comer o un trago.

Comment: @abrahamhs artLa nomNotacion adjHungara advNo advSiempre verHace artLas nomVariables advMas adjAmigables conY adjSu nomUso proSe verDesaconseja